# trigger hover behaviour for multiple layers of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page on which I have a grid of images. The opacity of these images is initially set to zero (ie, they are hidden). When the mouse is moved over an image, its opacity is immediately set to 1, and when the mouse is moved off, its opacity quickly fades back to zero. Relevant code looks like so:

HTML

```
<img class="Image" src="./img/foo.png">
```

CSS

```
.Image {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(".CircleImage").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(0,1);  // mouseenter
    },
    function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(200,0);  // mouseleave
    }
);
```

Now: I'd like to add some links that will be displayed *above* this grid of images. Here's the catch: I'd like for the images to maintain their hover behaviour. The really tricky bit is that the text of each link will span multiple images, and the size of the link text and images are dynamically altered with window size.

For example, say I had a link, the text of which was "click me," and at one particular window size, the "cli" of "click" was over one image, and the "me" over another. I would like the page to behave such that when the mouse is over the "cli" the image below it appears, when it is over the "me" the image below that bit of text appears, and all the while the link can be clicked.

**That is: I'd like for the hover behaviour to be triggered not only for the topmost element, but elements beneath it as well.**

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could accomplish this?

Comment: @jkjenner it sounds like you've got it all figured out. You even used the word `trigger` which is exactly what you need. `$('.CircleImage').trigger('hover')`

Comment: Can you show what the actual markup would look like? This sounds possible, depending on your markup.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I don't think you can trigger `hover` that way as it's actually `mouseover` and `mouseout`. `hover()` is just the shorthand function for `bind('mouseover', function(){}).bind('mouseout', function(){})`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Apologies, I should have been more clear: in some cases, I'll have link text that spans multiple images. Also, both the text size and image size/position are dynamically altered with window size, so the overlaps are not consistent. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the image and link in a container and change the opacity of that container.

```
<span class="imgContainer">
    <a href="#">X</a>
    <img class="Image" src="./img/foo.png" width="100" height="100">
</span>

.imgContainer {
    opacity: 0.1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.imgContainer a {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/E58uH/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is super close to what I'm after, but: in most cases, the link text will span multiple images. So, various images may need to be revealed or hidden depending on where one is hovering over the link. I'll edit my question to make this more clear.